# How to import data about mountain and then plot it?

Tags: plotting, graphics, import, geography, entity

There is a code for the [Mount Everest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest)

```
data = GeoElevationData[
GeoBoundingBox[
GeoDisk[Entity["Mountain", "MountEverest"], Quantity[5, "Miles"]]]]

ListPlot3D[data, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Red, 
Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

it is possible to do same thing for another mountain

for instance: mountain in [bakhmaro](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE)

[image]

but unfortunately this isn't entity object in *Mathematica*.

Does there exist any way to do this?

Is it possible to import information from [google earth](https://www.google.com/earth/) about this mountain to construct `data` like Mount Everest?

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.academia.edu/1490349/Do_It_Myself_HOW_TO_EXTRACT_ELEVATION_FROM_GOOGLE_EARTH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GeoElevationData` has elevation data for the whole world. If you know the position (I hope I interpreted correctly the Wikipedia data from your link):

```
In[]:= p = GeoPosition[{FromDMS[{42, 19, 32.}], FromDMS[{41, 51, 06.}]}]
Out[]= GeoPosition[{42.3256, 41.8517}]
```

then you can evaluate your same commands, replacing the entity by that position:

```
data = GeoElevationData[GeoBoundingBox[GeoDisk[p, Quantity[5, "Miles"]]]]

ListPlot3D[Reverse[data], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Filling -> Bottom,
           FillingStyle -> Red, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, BoundaryStyle -> None,
           Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```